# Can somebody explain the logic for inorder tree travesal?

Tags: data-structures, inorder

I got the output for below code but i am not getting the exact logic.
Line 3(recursive fn call) will pass the value `Null` when it reaches leaf node , then how can it print the data part

```
void Inorder(struct node *node)
{
  if(node!=NULL)
  {
     Inorder(node->left);
     printf("%d",node->data);
     Inorder(node->right);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically at every recursive call you continue if the node is not null.
Hence the call `node->left` for the leaf node would not continue further and the nodes get printed in the next line as the recursive function unfolds.

Dry run an example and verify for yourself.